# A metric $w$ on a Kahler manifold is extremal if and only if the gradient vector field of the scalar curvature is holomorphic

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

I am trying to understand the calculation in [An introduction to Extremal kahler metrics](https://www3.nd.edu/~gszekely/notes.pdf). On the fourth line of page 55 the author calculated that $\int_{M} - 2 S R^{\bar k j} \partial_{j} \partial_{\bar k}  \varphi = \int_{M} \varphi  \nabla_{j} \nabla_{\bar k}( -2 S R^{\bar k j})$, why is this true?

My thinking is：Consider $-2S R^{\bar k j}\partial_{\bar k} \varphi$, which is a section of $T^{1,0} M$, then we look at the quantity $\nabla_{j} -2 S R^{\bar k j} \partial_{\bar k} \varphi = \nabla_{j} -2S R^{\bar k j} \partial_{\bar k} \varphi - 2S R^{\bar k j}\partial_{j} \partial_{\bar k} \varphi$. This line of reasoning will result in different order of covariant derivatives than then one appearing in the reference. I do not really see how the equality should follow.

My apology if this is too elementary for mathoverflow, but I have been stuck for a while and could not find any thing related to this either online or in math stack exchange.

Comment: still looking for an answer...

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly where in that document the calculation is done. Without that it's hard to say exactly. However,  it looks like it's using integration by parts twice.

Comment: oh I am sorry, and it is in P55. I totally forgot to put it in the description.

Comment: wouldn't integration by parts result in $\nabla_{\bar k}\nabla_{j}R^{\bar k j}S$? @GabeK

Comment: Initially that seems like it would be the case, but I suspect the order of differentiation doesn't change the answer here. In particular, curvature only appears when you take mixed covariant derivatives of vector fields, so we should expect that $\int_{M} - 2 S R^{\bar k j} \partial_{j} \partial_{\bar k}  \varphi = \int_{M} - 2 S R^{\bar k j} \partial_{\bar k}  \partial_{j}  \varphi $, at which point integration by parts twice gets what you want. I'm not 100% sure of that though, so that should definitely be checked.

Comment: That actually makes sense, thank you. One could first change the differentiation order for $\partial_{\bar k} \partial_{j} \varphi$ as you suggested, then it works through. But it is strange that if we do not do this, and get $\nabla_{\bar k} \nabla_{j} R^{\bar k j} S$, then we switch the order of the covariant derivative, it will certainly produce some extra term.

Comment: That was confusing to me as well, which is why I wasn't 100% sure. Somehow the extra terms will need to cancel and I didn't see why that is the case.

Comment: "it will certainly produce some extra term": in fact, if you just write down the error term that you get when commuting these 2 covariant derivatives, you will get precisely zero